# Error using -eq in ternary operator ($var -eq 0 ? 1 : 0) in bash

Tags: bash, conditional-operator

I have the following Bash snippet in a larger Bash script:

```
if [ $COMMAND -le 1 ]; then
  test $COMMAND -eq 0 && echo 1>&2 -e "\n${COLORED_ERROR} No command selected.${ANSI_NOCOLOR}"
  echo ""
  echo "Synopsis:"
  echo "  Script to simulate '$ModuleName' module testbenches with Riviera-PRO."
  echo ""
  echo "..."

  test $COMMAND -eq 0 && exit 1 || exit 0
fi
```

```

The focus is on `test $COMMAND -eq 0 && exit 1 || exit 0`
**Edit:** The type of `$COMMAND` is an integer.

Is there a better way to conditionally calculate the exit code?

I found a `c ? a : b` operator on some websites talking about Bash arithmetic, but I couldn't get to work:

`exit $(($COMMAND -eq 0 ? 1 : 0`

Error message:

> ./tools/GitLab-CI/Riviera-PRO.run.sh: line 111: 1 -eq 0 ? 1 : 0 : syntax error in expression (error token is "0 ? 1 : 0 ")

---

Please note, `$COMMAND` uses multiple integer values:

- 0 - no command
- 1 - help
- 2 - command 1
- 3 - ...

Comment: What does `COMMAND` contain?

Comment: is it a command that exits with an integer value? Is it an integer returned by a prior command?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't put commands in strings **at all**; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I suspect COMMAND is a numeric value (probably input by a user) to select a command to execute and the actual command that will be executed is later in the script. The posted code looks like it's just verifying that a value has been entered, it just has a bad/misleading choice of variable name.

Comment: Note, by the way, that all-caps variables are in a namespace that the shell and POSIX-specified commands are allowed to use for their own purposes. To avoid conflicts with names meaningful to other tools, your own variables should have lower-case names; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Comment: ...as another aside, note that `echo -e` is not portable -- POSIX-compliant shells aren't allowed to have it do anything other than emit `-e` on output (so bash breaks the specification in this regard, unless configured with both `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags enabled). Much better to use `printf`; for example, `printf '%s\n' "one line" "another line"` prints two lines without requiring `\n`s to be embedded in the data (so you don't need to worry about how backslashes in that data will behave). See also the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX spec for `echo` itself, advising `printf` instead.

Comment: It's an integer as shown in the note. Thanks @CharlesDuffy I didn't know about the variable casing rules regarding shells / Bash. I'll read about that. The script is not targeting POSIX conformance, only Bash. While `printf` might be more conforming, it is not so readable than simple `echo`.

Comment: `echo` isn't "simple", though -- its behavior varies depending on context and configuration (like the aforementioned `xpg_echo` flag, which can even have its default changed at bash's compilation time!), so a reader can't be sure of what it will do without taking a lot of context into account. It *looks* simple, but using it makes a careful code reviewer's job harder.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking *only* about how to correct your use of the ternary operator -- you need to use `==`, not `-eq`, inside an arithmetic context:

```
retval=1
exit $(( (retval == 0) ? 1 : 0 ))
```

That said, if you want to exit with a successful status only if another command failed, that's as simple as:

```
! somecommand # run somecommand, and set $? to 0 only if it exited with an error
exit          # use $? as our own exit status
```

Comment: Any reason other than clarity and answering the OPs question on how to code a ternary expression to not just use `exit $(( retval == 0 ))`?

Comment: Not particularly -- the goal there was very much to showcase correct ternary use, so the OP could also do something like `(( (retval == 3) ? 5 : 7 ))` -- but you make a good point that there isn't a compelling use case for the ternary here at all.

Comment: I figured, just wanted to check if there was one of those pesky insidious edge cases lurking with the briefer form.

Comment: Why is `-eq` not allowed? It's an integer not a string, so in other places it's strongly advised to use `-eq` for integer comparison then `==`. Actually, it's two different operations: one is equality the other identity.

Comment: `-eq` is a `test` operator. `test` is the command also named `[`, and its operators are only available as arguments to that command (whichever name it's called under). (`[[` is ksh/bash extended syntax which also honors the syntax defined by and for `test`, but outside of `[`, `[[` or `test`, those primitives don't have any meaning).

Comment: ...no, `==` isn't identity -- it's a nonstandard name for the *string* equality comparison, `=`, in `test` (which in `[[` instead acts as a pattern-matching operator). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, defining `=` (`==` being nonstandard, it isn't defined at all).

Comment: In an arithmetic context as created by `(( ))`, by contrast, `=` and `==` have the same meaning they have in C syntax -- assignment for the former, arithmetic equality comparison for the latter.